# Mysql removing x value form an Json column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update my column because I'm working on a "Kick from Team" function. I've tried different solutions that I've found on google.

My first attempt was this:

```js
UPDATE table SET aMembers = JSON_REMOVE(aMembers, '$[1]') WHERE id = 1
```

aMembers looks like (Column type: JSON) :

```json
[1, 2, 8, 99, 12, 233, 819]
```

That works somewhat. It'll remove the given index from aMembers. This is not what I'm after tho. I'm after something that'll remove value 1 from aMembers.

Alright, then I tried this one:

```js
UPDATE table SET aMembers = JSON_REMOVE(aMembers, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(aMembers, 'one', '1'))) WHERE id = 1
```

This sets my whole column as NULL which is also not what I'm looking for. Am I doing this wrong or is this just not possible? Is there a query that'll remove id 1 from my column or am I forced to

```
 1. With js - Get column aMembers
 2. Find out at which index ID 1 is at
 3. Create a new query that'll remove index X
```

For DB I am using MariaDB.
For my frontend I am using NextJS.
Backend is NodeJS.

Comment: JSON_SEARCH() *Returns the path to the given **string** within a JSON document*. Whereas your values are integers.

Comment: @Akina Oh. So I am guessing I can't be using JSON_SEARCH to find the index? Those are basically examples I've found. No knowledge (not enough) within sql.  Any fixes I can do to maybe make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I chose to solve this by using index. Each time I print the members out they will be printed in the same positions as in the JSON column which means that I can simply use index to remove x member from the column.

So each child, when printed out, get's an Index prop and this prop is being set to my api that kicks them. This then updates the JSON in mysql table row to remove index x from the column.